# Is there a way to AND across a row of a 2D Array?

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA, I would like to AND across each row in a 2D array and star the result in separate 1D array without ANDing a single pair the ANDing the result with the next item in that row.

FYI This is my first time using 2D arrays so sorry if there is an obvious solution.

For example if the data in my sheet looked like this (the actual range is much larger):

[image]

I would like to do the equlavant of an excel formula: =AND(B2:D2) then =AND(B3:D3), etc...

I have code that sets everything up but I don't know how to proceed except to loop across each element of a row, store the result then loop across the next, etc, etc. I'm hoping the there is a much better (more efficient) way to proceed.

Here is my code so far

```
Sub Exceptions()
    ' Setup worksheet
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = cnTest
        
    ' Find last row of range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Find_LastRow(wks)   'Functionthat returns last row
             
    ' load range into array
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    MyArray = wks.Range("B2:D8")
    
    ' Setup 1D Result array
    Dim Results As Variant
    Results = wks.Range("A2:A8")
    

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        ' Perform AND function on each row of the array
        ' then place result in 1D array (Results())
        ' If this were a formul: =AND(B2:D2)
        '
        ' Is there way to "AND" across a row in and array or
        ' must I "AND" MyArray(1,1) with MyArray(1,2) then AND
        ' that result with MyArray(1,3)
    Next i
          
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Btw, note that `Results = wks.Range("A2:A8")` is a 2D array, not a 1D array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub Exceptions()
    ' Setup worksheet

        

             
    ' load range into array
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    MyArray = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:D8")
    
    ' Setup 1D Result array
    Dim Results As Variant
    Results = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A8")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim X As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray, 1)
        Results(i, 1) = "True"
        For X = 1 To UBound(MyArray, 2)
            If MyArray(i, X) = False Then
                Results(i, 1) = "False"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next X
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You can shorten and save an `IF`.. Remove the `If X = UBound(MyArray, 2) ... End if` and, right after the `For i =..` line insert `Results(i, 1) = True`

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim vR()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    
    Set rngDB = Range("b2:b8")
    r = rngDB.Rows.Count
    ReDim vR(1 To r)
    
    For Each rng In rngDB
        i = i + 1
        vR(i) = WorksheetFunction.And(rng.Resize(1, 3))
    Next rng
    Range("a2").Resize(r) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the formula bar, type:

```
=IF(-PRODUCT(IF(A1,-1,0),IF(C1,-1,0)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

(if the data is in columns A and C), and drag down.

Because, as everyone knows, `A AND B = AB` if `A` and `B` are Boolean variables (and watch the minus in front of the `PRODUCT`).